# Can an old SSD be the cause of daily freeze on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, freeze, reboot

I have an old computer with the X58 chipset that started randomly freezing and rebooting after I upgraded to Windows 10.

This is the component list:

- Gigabyte GA-X58-USB3 motherboard
- Core i7 950 with Akasa Nero 2 Air Cooler
- 24 GB of Kingston DDR3 1333
- 120 GB OCZ Agility 2
- 1 TB Samsung disk
- 600w OCZ PSU 80 PLUS (OCZ600SXS)

I tested all the possible variations of my components:

- removed the GTX 660 and tested with a GT 210 to check if it was the GPU
- stressed test with prime95 for 10h on Windows 10 and it passed all the tests, temps stable at 70/71º C, drawing 290w maximum from the wall (measured with a kill-a-watt)
- removed a 1tb 7200RPM disk without sucessess

Could the problem be the SSD? The smart test says it's ok, but since it's a very old drive that only supports SATA2, I was wondering if Windows 10 is somehow incompatible with it. Could that be the cause?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible but hard to know for sure...have you checked your drive's SMART info? I like [CrystalDiskMark](http://crystalmark.info/download/index-e.html)

Comment: Windows Event Viewer might have some events you can Google.  I never bought an OCZ SSD, but they have a utility which might give you more information : https://ocz.com/us/download/ssd-utility .  Time consuming test : Try swapping the SSD for a spare HD, and installing the OS to that.  If it works, you know what the problem component was.

Comment: I have owned a few OCZ SSDs over the years, they're a very early generation of drive and almost all of the drives I bought have died over the years.  If you have a spare SSD somewhere, use it and see if there's any difference.

Comment: Just checked CrystalDisk and it says the health status is "Good 100%" and the drive has 8896 GB total reads and 8128 GB total write. I couldn't download the OCZ tool (apparently it's no longer available), but I remembered I used it in the past to update the drive firmeware.

Comment: I decided to test a theory about the AHCI driver in Windows 10. I saved an image of the drive as a backup and changed the BIOS from SATA AHCI to SATA IDE and performed a clean installation of Windows, the same version I had before. So far it's going ok, I ran prime95 for the past two hours, updated windows, watched a few 4k videos on YouTube without any problems. I will test for the next days to see if the AHCI setting was the issue.

Comment: Here you can download the OCZ SSD Utility. http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/HDD-SSD-NAS-USB-Flash/OCZ/OCZ-SSD-Utility-202430.shtml